# Airflow webserver throwing error -Socket error processing request

Tags: airflow, gunicorn

Our webserver is running and working fine. Although in the logs we are seeing these errors periodically . Can someone provide pointers around these

```
[2022-04-05 02:53:58 -0400] [129502] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/airflow/airflowvirt/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    req = next(parser)
  File "/airflow/airflowvirt/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/http/parser.py", line 42, in __next__
    self.mesg = self.mesg_class(self.cfg, self.unreader, self.source_addr, self.req_count)
  File "/airflow/airflowvirt/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 180, in __init__
    super().__init__(cfg, unreader, peer_addr)
  File "/airflow/airflowvirt/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 54, in __init__
    unused = self.parse(self.unreader)
  File "/airflow/airflowvirt/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 192, in parse
    self.get_data(unreader, buf, stop=True)
  File "/airflow/airflowvirt/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 183, in get_data
    data = unreader.read()
  File "/airflow/airflowvirt/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 37, in read
    d = self.chunk()
  File "/airflow/airflowvirt/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 64, in chunk
    return self.sock.recv(self.mxchunk)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 956, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 833, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 592, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
[2022-04-05 02:53:58 -0400] [129500] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
```

Comment: check if this help here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619559/socket-error-processing-request-with-flask-gunicorn-docker-and-azure

Comment: @Rafa did you find solution? i see same error